# Pytest runs tests twice in the specific configuration

Tags: python-2.7, pytest

I started to use pytest.
I created testing environment:

[image: my environment]

When I run pytest with different options everything works well. For example in pytest.ini:

> addopts = -rxs --full-trace -v --color=yes --durations=3  --junit-xml="c:\tmp\log.xml"

But when I want to run test by nodeID, for example:

> addopts = -vv Unit/Flows/test_my1.py::TestClass1

pytest runs tests twice.
**How can I avoid this?**

Comment: What are your plugins? I had this bug too, each test case was being run twice. I'm on win32, I have uninstalled pytest-xdist, pytest-django-sqlcount, pytest-spec, pytest-smartcov and the problem disappeared. Pytest 2.7.1 on Python 2.7

Comment: I have pytest-xdist and coverage. But I need pytest-xdist :) I'll try to uninstall and see what happens...